# Работа с потоками golang

Tags: golang, tls, mutex

К примеру есть два потока которые используют функции для TLS.
Приведу 2 функции для примера (в принципе содержимое неинтересно):

```
func init(){
 Activ =  make(chan int, 1)
}

type Nomenc struct{}

func (u *Nomenc) Ping() error {
    Activ <- 1
    reply := make([]byte, 64)
    if err := send([]byte("PING"), ConnectTls); err != nil {
        <-Activ
        return err
    }
    n, err := read(&reply, ConnectTls)
    if err != nil {
        <-Activ
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("UserNomenclature:" + string(reply[:n]))
    <-Activ
    return nil
}

func (u *Nomenc) SelectOne(Type, Query string) error {
    Activ <- 1
    reply, Q := make([]byte, 16384), models.QueryMessage{Table: Type, Query: Query}
    Bytes1, err := json.Marshal(Q)
    if err != nil {
        <-Activ
        return err
    }
    if err := send([]byte(string(Bytes1)), ConnectTls); err != nil {
        <-Activ
        return err
    }
    n, err := read(&reply, ConnectTls)
    if err != nil {
        <-Activ
        return err
    }
    id, mes := string(reply[0:2]), string(reply[3:n])
    if id == "00" {
        <-Activ
        return errors.New("Error:" + mes)
    } else {
        if Query == "Count" {
            fmt.Println("mes:", string(mes))
            if u.Obj, err = strconv.ParseInt(string(mes), 10, 64); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error:", err.Error())
                <-Activ
                return err
            }
            fmt.Println("u.Obj:", u.Obj)
        }
    }
    <-Activ
    return nil
}
```

Но можно заметить что для синхронизации применяются каналы. Т.е. если в канале сейчас что то есть то параллельно функции не вызываются. Вопрос: как сделать по человечески? С использованием мьютексов или тех же каналов?

Пояснение зачем это нужно: Если во время чтения функцией SelectOne() будет вызвана функция PING ответ от нее (PONG) вклинится в поток передачи и данные будут не корректны.

Comment: У вас разделяемый ресурс - Connect tls. Самый простой способ - когда используете его (read/send), делайте его блокировку. А ещё лучше спрятать блокировки внутрь структуры (сделать её threadsafe)

Comment: Если я его запихну внутрь структуры, она будет генерироваться по новой каждый раз при объявлении объекта структуры. А чем сделать блокировку read/send?

Comment: Мьютексом. sync.Mutex